# How to make secure route in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a application with **Laravel 5.2**. I have some route. Now i want to make few routes secure so that anyone can not guessing and insert any value.Now i want to add some character before `{id}` and after `{id}` So that anyone can't reach it by guessing.

```
Route::get('/prize/{id}','PrizeCalculateController@showPrizePage');
```

Now user can go to `localhost/laravel/public/prize/1` or replace 1 by anything and can go to that url. I want make it secure so that anyone can't go by guessing.

I have tried with:

```
$parameter = $qrcode->id;
$encryption= Crypt::encrypt($parameter);
```

What will be the best approach to make a route secure?

Comment: I think it's best to use `middleware`. Please see the docs! https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: @HirenGohel i have used `middleware` for users. But i want to make any user can't visit this url typing `../prize/12` etc `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypt the ID will generate a very long (188+ chatacters) string, not so friendly.

You can generate an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (32 characters) to represent your model. There's many packages that generates and validate UUID, for example [this one](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid).

To use the UUID, you should create a column on your table to represent it, and load the model by the `uuid` field instead of `id`.

Since the UUID represents a very large number (128 bits one), is very hard to guess it (virtually impossible, one chance in 3.402823669×10³⁸).

Also do difficult guessing (the probability increases as your table size increase), you can expire the UUID periodically (or invalidate it if used for example). There are many ways to secure it, but all depends on your application design.

Since you do not need the `universally unique` part of UUID, you can also just generate a big random string using `str_random()` helper from Laravel. A 16 alphanumeric characters string is also very strong (4.767240171×10²⁸ combinations).

Consider add a rate limiting to this route also make it very hard to guess.

Comment: I think `str_random()` will serve my purpose. Could you tell me how will i do that? I mean i will generate this string in controller then passes this into the url?

Answer (score 0):

I use this lib to hash IDs: http://hashids.org/php/

Here's my wrapper for Laravel:

```
public static function staticHash($number, $obfuscate = false)
{
   $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(\Config::get('app.key'));

   return $hashids->encode($number);
}


public static function staticHashDecode($hash, $obfuscate = false)
{
   $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(\Config::get('app.key'));
   $number = $hashids->decode($hash);

   if (isset($number[0])) {
      $number = $number[0];
   } else {
      $number = false;
   }

   return $number;
}
```